# Как пользоваться десятичными числами в mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Как пользоваться десятичными числами в mysql? Какой тип в бд нужен для десятичных чисел?

Есть число  1.23, как добавлять в эту строку, например, 0.01?

Comment: http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/Numeric_types.html

Советую вот это для начала почитать.

Comment: @iksuy Прочитал, а как в таблице записывать десятичные числа? Сделал тип DECIMAL, а он не записывает десятичные, только простые и на странице тоже показывает простое число.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Плохо читали

> > Требуемая точность данных и масштаб могут задаваться (и обычно задаются)
> > при объявлении столбца данных одного
> > из этих типов, например:

```
salary DECIMAL(5,2)
```

> > В этом примере - 5 (точность)
> > представляет собой общее количество
> > значащих десятичных знаков, с которыми
> > будет храниться данная величина, а
> > цифра 2 (масштаб) задает количество
> > десятичных знаков после запятой.
> > Следовательно, в этом случае интервал
> > величин, которые могут храниться в
> > столбце salary, составляет от -99,99
> > до 99,99 (в действительности для
> > данного столбца MySQL обеспечивает
> > возможность хранения чисел вплоть до
> > 999,99, поскольку можно не хранить
> > знак для положительных чисел).

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffad82